# How to access files in file:///android_assets/?

Tags: android, android-assets, android-developer-api

Is it possible to access the files inside

> file:///android_assets/

of an installed android application(in emulator or actual device) through `DDMS` or any other tool?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That folder is inside the .APK, therefore you need to find it, download it into your computer and unzip it.

Yes, you can do it trough DDMS or trough adb, but you probably need to have the device rooted first.

Comment: I have installed the apk in emulator. Where can i find the android_assets folder in ddms? It is not present in /data/data/com.app.mobile or in /sdcard.

Comment: your device is rooted ?